# Django : multiple app urls

Tags: django

I have a django project which consists of 2 apps - `bigapp` and `smallapp`.
My issue is that I cant seem to access `smallapp` through my browser. AFAIK I have the `urls` setup exactly I have in `bigapp`. All pages in `bigapp` are accessible but `smallapp` always gives me the `Page Not found error`.
My files are as follows:

```
`smallapp/views.py`

class Basicview(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
        #code

class DetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
        #code
        return render(request, 'smallapp/detail.html', context)
```

`smallapp/urls.py`

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from .views import BasicView, DetailView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^/$', DetailView.as_view(), name='small_app'),
    url(
        r'^new_app_view/',
        BasicView.as_view(),
        name='small_app_view'
    ),
]
```

in the main `urls.py`

i added the line:

```
url(r'^smallapp', include('smallapp.urls', namespace='smallapp')),
```

Now when I start my server using `python manage.py runserver`. I open my browser, and when I type `localhost:8000/new_app_view` I keep getting the page not found error

Comment: That should be:`localhost:8000/smallapp/new_app_view`. BTW, you're missing a trailing slash in main `urls.py` file after `^smallapp`.

Comment: And probably you are also missing a $ at the end of  r'^new_app_view/$'

Comment: I've added both your suggestions and it works. Thanks a lot. I had tried `localhost:8000/smallapp/new_app_view` only to end up with the page not found error